# ElasticSearch Sense webUI - How to see full JSON output (when initially truncated)?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, sense

In seemingly all web browsers, **[ElasticSearch Sense webUI](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/sense/current/introduction.html) initially truncates the output view of JSON** - In this screenshot, you can see the output truncated, as you don't see closing JSON curly braces '}' at the bottom of visible output:

[image]

**How can I see the full output un-truncated?**

I am posting initial Answers here that I discovered, and in general, I'm posting this to help others, as I haven't found any report of this "bug" or solutions anywhere on the web.

*Side question*: **Does ElasticSearch Sense have any bug reporting mechanism?**  I would have already reported this bug if I could find how; so this is another reason I am posting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magnify your web browser larger (I think it might also work with smaller) - then output is expanded, like you can see in this image, as you can now see the closing curly braces '&' at the bottom of JSON output (I collapsed the "otherNames" mapping so it all fits within this view).

[image]

This seems to "persist" the fix:  No truncation in any further queries, or after refresh (even hard), or cache clear.  Although I'm not sure if it would become truncated again after a machine restart...

Answer (score 0):

The full output actually is there, but it has an invisible scroll bar.  Still doesn't explain why the scrolling pane itself is truncated.

This is more of a "workaround", while my other Answer here describes how to persistently "fix" it.